# loading a web component from a lib subdirectory

Tags: dart, dart-webui

When trying to insert a html file for a webcomponent into the views directory in my application library, the web_ui compiler throws the message

```
FileIOException: Cannot retrieve full path for file 'lib\src\view\entity\base\packages' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is this to be expected? If not, what should I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't see your code or project, this is just a hunch. I believe your web component HTML file imports some components the wrong way.

Try the follow this structure:

```
/lib/src/view/foo/foo.html
/lib/src/view/foo/foo.dart

/lib/src/view/bar/bar.html
/lib/src/view/bar/bar.dart
```

And inside `foo.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="components" href="../bar/bar.html" />
  </head>
<body>
  <element name="x-foo" constructor="FooComponent" extends="div">
    <template>
      ...
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="foo.dart"></script>
  </element>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I'm not using `packages` in `foo.html`.